# compiling jar with different version of jdk using maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm having client jar which need to be compiled with jdk 1.5 and jdk 1.6. I want to maintain  same artifactId and version. I'm planning to use maven classifier to download the artifact from nexus. Although i use `jdk5` profile for building the jar (`mvn clean install -Pjdk5`), by looking at manifest file i find this - `Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_51`

- Is jar's manifest file which will tell the jdk version with which artifact has been compiled ?
- How to get the both artifact out with one maven build command ?

  ```
  <profiles>
  <profile>
      <id>jdk5</id>
      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.3.2</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <source>1.5</source>
                      <target>1.5</target>
                      <fork>true</fork>
                      <executable>${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac</executable>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
              <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                      <classifier>jdk5</classifier>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
  </profile>
  <profile>
      <id>jdk6</id>
      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.3.2</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <source>1.6</source>
                      <target>1.6</target>
                      <fork>true</fork>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
              <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                      <classifier>jdk6</classifier>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
  </profile>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken into consideration the binaries compiled with jdk 5 will be compatible with jre 6 or above? Newer jre version always runs binaries compiled with older jdk version.

The `source` and `target` settings on maven-compiler-plugin just sets source code validation and what minimum target runtime it's intended for. So in your case I recommend you set both source and target to 1.5

If you really have to compile with both jdk5 and 6 then you can set your JAVA_HOME env var to corresponding jdk installation and run your maven command for each version.

If you want to check it, on command prompt before you compile do a `mvn -version`. It will tell you what jdk version is used

Comment: You have answered one part correctly. mvn -version and manifest both shows the jdk which is set as JAVA_HOME. In this case, i don't see use of executable configuration. How do i get both artifact together ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible using one maven command. Your best bet is using script that runs 2 maven commands with each jdk respectively. You can use maven variablue (`${myvar}`) as part of the version and supply it using `-Dmyvar=jdk5` to distinguish the artifact

Answer (score 0):

The manifest entry (Build-Jdk) dont tell the jdk used to compile but the ${java.version}. To have different manifest in the 2 jars, the simpliest is to write your own (2*) manifests.

[maven doc: Manifest](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifest.html)

You can do it in one mvn command without profile (note: it is a bad practice to have two artifacts generated from one pom)

You have to double compiler, jar (or other packaging) and resource plugins
This example generate jdk1.8 jar (with classifier) in addition to the default (jdk1.7) jar.

Be carefull i use absolute path to point to the 2 jdk bin path, this wont work in continous integration development project.

[maven doc:Compiling Sources Using A Different JDK](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.erbre.test</groupId>
<artifactId>multi-compilation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile-jdk1.8</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}_jdk1.8</outputDirectory>
                        <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\javac</executable>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-package</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-package-jdk1.8</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}_jdk1.8</classesDirectory>
                        <classifier>jdk1.8</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testResources</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testResources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-resources-jdk1.8</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}_jdk1.8</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```